# How to monitor local storage disk space on Azure Cloud Service Worker Role- PAAS

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles, paas

Last week I had a situation where I ran out of disk space of local storage for my PAAS worker role cloud service.

After some basic research I have found that there is a setting(cleanOnRoleRecyle) in Service Definition file to clear the local storage on role recycle.

Additionally to this I am wondering is there any metric I can add and monitor the disk space and send out alerts if it is running low.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively there isn't a metric you can choose for PaaS Roles (theoretically you can leverage the underlying Windows Metrics but they would require setup).  You can look at other solutions from the likes of NewRelic or AzureWatch (Paraleap) to provide access to better metrics (or the event log) on a Worker Role.